# Sumar 2 array, y determinar el resultado en un tercer arreglo

Tags: php

Como puedo realizar la suma de 2 arreglos y en un tercer array obtener la suma de estos?
esto es lo que llevó

pero tengo un fatal error.

```
<?php
$datos1 = array (3,5,4,3,2);
$datos2 = array (7,8,1,4,6);
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $resultado[$i] = $datos1[$i] + $datos2[$i] ;
```

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes esta correcto, solo debes agregar una llave al final que te falta. `$datos1 = array (3,5,4,3,2);
$datos2 = array (7,8,1,4,6);
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $resultado[$i] = $datos1[$i] + $datos2[$i] ;
}

var_dump($resultado);`

Comment: Hola cuando dices sumar te refieres * ¿a que quieres que se sumen `$datos1[$i] + $datos1[$i]` siendo como resultado `10`? * ¿O qué los dos `arreglos` se vuelvan uno solo? > Una sugerencia es que inicialices el tercer arreglo vacio y es bueno que coloques el error que te da cuando ejecutas tu código.

Comment: quiero sumar los valorres de datos 1 + los valores de datos 2 
3+7
5+8
4+1, etc y los resultados obtenerlos en un tercer arreglo

Comment: Hola lo siento honestamente me salte ese paso y pase directo a responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Declara una variable que almacenará el vector generado por la suma de cada columna de valores
- Dentro del `for` indica que la variable `$i` sea menor a 5 y que inicie en 0 pues esa es la longitud de tus vectores
- Pasa la variable del vector vacío dentro del for así: `$total[]` e igualala a la suma de ambos vectores en cada iteración del `for` identificado por la letra `$i`
- Imprime por fuera del `for` por medio de un `var_dump()` a la variable `$total`
- La variable `$total` la declaramos por fuera del `for` para evitar que si fuera dentro de, se creará una y otra vez

Así:

```
<?php

$datos1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 3);
$datos2 = array(5, 6, 7, 8, 4);

$total = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $total[] = $datos1[$i] + $datos2[$i];
}

var_dump($total);
```

Dando esto como resultado:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(6)
  [1]=>
  int(8)
  [2]=>
  int(10)
  [3]=>
  int(12)
  [4]=>
  int(7)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser por que en tu `for` se sale del indice de los arreglos ya que el tamaño es de `5`, por lo que el recorrido sera mientras `$i` sea menor al tamaño del array, el error pasaba al momento que el indice accedía a una posición que no tiene datos

Ejemplo:

```
$datos1 = array (3,5,4,3,2);
$datos2 = array (7,8,1,4,6);
for ($i = 0; $i <count($datos1); $i++) {
    $resultado[$i] = $datos1[$i] + $datos2[$i];
```